# not getting date properly from the xls sheet

Tags: php, xls

I'm using ubuntu for my coding.,

I'm importing the xls file data into my controller, in which one field is date, I've formatted the cell with date format, when I look into the imported data everything is fine but the date field is getting displayed as number,

for eg: the entered date is `2013-05-10` it showed me as `39942`

then after to check the thing I've changed the format of the cell to number by keeping the date value as it is then it showed me a value `39942` which is same as the value that I got into my controller..!
How can I get the correct date after importing,

Any help regarding this..?

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores date/times as serialized float timestamps, the number of days since Jan 1st 1900 (or Jan 1st 1904, depending on Windows or Mac calendar), and remembering that it considers 1900 as a leap year.

Taken directly from the PHPExcel Date handling code:

```
public static function ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0) {
    if (self::$ExcelBaseDate == self::CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900) {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
        //    Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        if ($dateValue < 60) {
            --$myExcelBaseDate;
        }
    } else {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 24107;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    // Return
    return $returnValue;
}    //    function ExcelToPHP()
```

Set self::$ExcelBaseDate == self::CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900 as necessary to indicate the Excel base calendar that you're using: Windows 1900 or Mac 1904

and if you want a PHP DateTime object instead:

```
public static function ExcelToPHPObject($dateValue = 0) {
    $dateTime = self::ExcelToPHP($dateValue);
    $days = floor($dateTime / 86400);
    $time = round((($dateTime / 86400) - $days) * 86400);
    $hours = round($time / 3600);
    $minutes = round($time / 60) - ($hours * 60);
    $seconds = round($time) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);

    $dateObj = date_create('1-Jan-1970+'.$days.' days');
    $dateObj->setTime($hours,$minutes,$seconds);

    return $dateObj;
}    //    function ExcelToPHPObject()
```